# Triggering a server to shutdown in receiving a signal via serial port (RS232)

Tags: shutdown, serial-port

I'm a fresh graduate (Electronics & Commn) and want to start my career in linux administration. I'm using a **Ubunutu 14.04 server machine** for R&D (**with ups**). Now my scenario is whenever main power supply goes off and ups gives backup, a message or signal has to be sent to the server machine and make it to shutdown. How to accomplish this task. Can anyone help me with this. (I'm ready to setup some embedded controller in ups if needs)

Comment: There is software to do this for a variety of UPS systems. See http://www.networkupstools.org and http://www.apcupsd.org

Comment: Thank you very much and sry for posting a question beyond the scope of this site's motivation.